# Declare setState via function

Tags: reactjs, setstate

Unable to declare setState via the function. And I can’t understand what the mistake is.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    text: ' ',
  };

  render() {
    const text = () => {
      this.setState({ text: 'Good afternoon' });
    };

    return(

    )
  }
}
```

Comment: the function should be outside render. Please see https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hh6v8c

Answer (score 0):

Functions and setState should be outside the render lifecycle.
More Info: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

SetState Guide: https://blog.logrocket.com/an-imperative-guide-to-setstate-in-react-b837ceaf8304/

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export default class App extends Component {

state = {      
      text: " "
   }

const text = () => {
         this.setState({text: "Good afternoon"})
      }

   render() {

return(

)

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please bring the function text outside the render function.

```
export default class App extends Component {
state = {
    text: ' ',
};

//function in here
text = () => {
    this.setState({ text: 'Good afternoon' });
}


render() {

    return ()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, when I pass the text of the function beyond the rendering limits, setState does not work.

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work? please share you've tried.